# MouseLeftButtonDown is not getting fired

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF user control that is dervied from UserControl class. MouseLeftButtonDown is not getting fired at all for the contol. I added event handler and also tried as follows.
I guess it is handled somewhere else, how to debug and find where is it getting hanlded.. Any help is appreciated!

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you have the Background of the UserControl set to something?  If not, try setting it to 
"Background=Transparent" and see if that works.  If it doesn't work, can you post the XAML for your UserControl, as well as the XAML for its usage?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a magic. Can you please explain me the logic behind this?

Comment: It's all about WPF's HitTesting mechanism and its treatment of null brushes vs Transparent brushes.  Here's a bit more information on this:  http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hit-testing-in-wpf/.