# Datagrid cell click opens new window with data from DB

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid and when I click a cell I want to open a new window which contains data from my DB linked to the ID of the cell I clicked.

To begin. I can't seem to open this window on a cell click. See code below.

```
<UserControl>
    <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.MouseLeftButtonDown"
                 Handler="CellClicked" />
    </Style>
</UserControl>
<DataGrid Name="grdNewTickets" BorderThickness="1" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Onderwerp" Width="Auto" 
                            Binding="{Binding Onderwerp}">       
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
private void CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var win = new Ticket();
    win.Show();
}
```

Some help?

UPDATE:
When I add a breakpoint, the CellClicked isn't triggered. Am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML needs to be corrected like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdNewTickets" BorderThickness="1"  MouseLeftButtonDown="CellClicked" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Onderwerp" Width="Auto" 
                            Binding="{Binding Onderwerp}">       
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In code behind,

```
private void CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           Ticket childWin= new Ticket();
            childWin.Show();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work. The "CellClicked" isn't triggered.

Comment: @user2287508 Your XAML is wrong! you want the cellclicked event for datagrid or usercontrol?

Comment: @user2287508 can you mark it as an answer, if it has helped you

Comment: It also triggers this event if I click in the datagrid that doesn't have any cell's

Answer (score 0):

try setting it to "Background=Transparent".

suddently worked for me

[MouseLeftButtonDown is not getting fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602250/mouseleftbuttondown-is-not-getting-fired)